# Sheets Scripts- Copy one cell to another cell, ignoring blank cells

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I have a script that will copy the value from a source cell to a target cell, but I am unable to figure out how to ignore a blank cell from being copied to the target cell.  I need to have the source ignore copying the blank value into the target cell.

This is where I am currently at:

```
    function CopyCellsCQF() { // Copies cells from bottom of sheet to individual selected cells
      var ss3 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

      ss3.getRange('CQF!B60').copyTo(ss3.getRange('CQF!J7'), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);       //Age #1 
      ss3.getRange('CQF!C60').copyTo(ss3.getRange('CQF!W7'), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);       //Age #2 
      ss3.getRange('CQF!D60').copyTo(ss3.getRange('CQF!H11:K11'), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);  //Amount
      ss3.getRange('CQF!F60').copyTo(ss3.getRange('CQF!E8:L8'), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);    //Email #1
      ss3.getRange('CQF!G60').copyTo(ss3.getRange('CQF!C6:J6'), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);    //Name #1
      ss3.getRange('CQF!H60').copyTo(ss3.getRange('CQF!D7:H7'), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);    //DOB #1
      ss3.getRange('CQF!I60').copyTo(ss3.getRange('CQF!L6'), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);       //Sex #1
      ss3.getRange('CQF!R60').copyTo(ss3.getRange('CQF!L6'), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);       //Sex #1  }
```

As you can see, the last two lines of the code below have 2 different sources but have the same target cell.  Only I60 or R60 will have a value at one time.  They never both will have a value in it at the same time.  As it is now if I60 has a value and R60 is blank, the script will write the value into L6 from I60 and then the Blank value from R60 will overwrite and place a blank value into L6.

Forgive me if this sounds confusing. Any help will be much appreciated.  Thank you

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot imagine `As you can see, the last two lines of the code below have 2 different sources but have the same target cell. Only I60 or R60 will have a value at one time. They never both will have a value in it at the same time. As it is now if I60 has a value and R60 is blank, the script will write the value into L6 from I60 and then the Blank value from R60 will overwrite and place a blank value into L6.`. In order to correctly understand question, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect as the image?

Comment: @Tanaike, Thank you for responding.  Yes, I could have worded it better.  Gustavo's answer below worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can treat each exception scenario separately.

If `CQF!I60` is NOT empty, copy that value to `CQF!L6`, if `CQF!R60` is NOT empty, copy that value to `CQF!L6`.

#### Sample Code:

```js
…
var sex1 = ss3.getRange('CQF!I60').getValue();
var sex2 = ss3.getRange('CQF!R60').getValue();

if (sex1.trim().length > 0){ //if sex1 is not empty…
//copy sex1 to target cell
ss3.getRange('CQF!L6').setValue(sex1);
};
if (sex2.trim().length > 0){ //if sex2 is not empty…
//copy sex2 to target cell ()
ss3.getRange('CQF!L6').setValue(sex2);
};
```

- Note: Just keep in mind that if both `CQF!I60` and `CQF!R60` have values, `CQF!L6` will be overwritten. However that might be intentional depending on your use case.

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for.  Thank you!